# Oracle: ISO Week, wrong answer

Tags: oracle, date

In Oracle 11 and Oracle 12, issuing the following select:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('19720101','YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYYIW') || ' ' || TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('19721230','YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYYIW') AS ERRATO FROM DUAL;
```

I get:

```
197252 197252
```

I expected something like:

```
197152 197252 or 197153 197252
```

Why do I get the same result 197252 197252?

Comment: If you want the year that belongs to the iso week, you need to use `IYYY` not `YYYY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently formatting with `'YYYYIW'` which is the 4 digit year, followed by the ISO week-of-year. I suspect you want the ISO week-year, followed by the ISO week-of-year.

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) is very unclear on this, but you should *try* `'IYYYIW'` as the format string instead. That uses the "4-digit year based on the ISO standard" (`IYYY`).

(I'm trying to run that on sqlfiddle to see if it works, but it's hung at the moment...)

Comment: You are perfectly right, I just realized.


    SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('19720101','YYYYMMDD')), 'IYYYIW') || ' ' || TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('19721230','YYYYMMDD')), 'IYYYIW') AS ERRATO FROM DUAL;

result:

    197152 197252

Thanks!

Comment: You should read the [manual for a supported Oracle version](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#r22c1-t64) - that is much clearer: "*4-digit year of the year containing the calendar week, as defined by the ISO 8601 standard*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for that. It's at least somewhat clearer, but I find it's even clearer to talk about "calendar year" and "week-year". ("Calendar week" is an odd term in itself, IMO.)

Comment: "Calendar week" is quite common expression in areas where people used to work with weeks. For example in German you say "Kalenderwoche" or just "KW" and usage is quite common (unlike in the U.S.)